# How to avoid '1' when incoming is none

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

i want result when incoming2 and incoming3 is none then it should avoid printing two '1' between incoming1 and incoming4.

```
def string_con(self,combined):
    if combined is none:
       return '1'
    else:
       return str(combined)

if incoming['col1'] or incoming['col1'] or incoming['col3'] or incoming['col4']:    
combined = self.string_con(incoming['col1'])+'1'+self.string_con(incoming['col2'])+'1'+self.string_con(incoming['col3'])+'1'+self.string_con(incoming['col4'])
```

```
Input1 : incoming['col1']=a incoming['col4']=d
Output1: a1111d 
Expected output1:a1d
```

```
Input2: incoming['col1']=a incoming['col2']=b 
Output2: a1b11 
Expected output2:a1b
```

Comment: You have a typo in your code -- > `if incoming['col1'] or incoming['col1']` ... guessing the second should say `incoming['col2']` ... is this the source of your error?

Comment: Could somebody clean up the english? I'm not really sure what's being asked.

Comment: `None`, not `none`. Capitalization is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the following:

```
req_keys = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']
all_list = [incoming[i] for i in req_keys]
all_list = [i for i in all_list if i]
print('1'.join(all_list))
```

Example:

```
incoming = {}
incoming['col1'] = 'a'
incoming['col2'] = None
incoming['col3'] = 'c'
incoming['col4'] = None
```

Output:

```
a1c
```

Another Example:

```
incoming = {}
incoming['col1'] = 'a'
incoming['col2'] = None
incoming['col3'] = None
incoming['col4'] = 'd'
```

Output:

```
a1d
```